# MessageBox doesn't show in Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: c#, .net, windows-embedded, windows-7-embedded

Consider a MessageBox to prompt the user to answer yes or no. It works in our XP machines and one Windows 7 build machine.

However, it doesn't work on our Windows 7 Embedded machine. There is no error message, no MessageBox shows up. It just assumes the user clicked the Yes button because I can find the debug file created from there and `createDatabase();` is called without any messageBox ahead of it.

I can find the assembly (System.Windows.Forms.dll) which is required by the MessageBox. It is in the same location as our Windows 7 build machine. do you have any idea why? thanks

```
DialogResult result = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
    "Do you want to update your database?\nWarning: All your data will be erased if you click Yes !",
"Update Database",
MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
MessageBoxIcon.Question);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    string[] cmdLines2 = { @"C:\AndeDB\AndeDB.db is here and selected yes" };
    //it will create, open and write or overwrite
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\dbcheck2.txt", cmdLines2);
    createDatabase();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/quebeccomponentsforum/thread/0437d230-cdda-4166-8788-887d2c946d4d) post, you could disable the "Message Box Default Reply" component from Windows 7 Embedded.  Further details can be found on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940743%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx).

Comment: Could u share solution for Windows XP pls?

Answer (score 4):

The keyword here is "embedded".  Such versions of Windows are often configured to run head-less (no monitor) or optimized to work without anybody being close.  A MessageBox is poison to such a configuration.  The machine stops running and nobody can find out why.

You need to go back to your system builder and find the option that controls this.